# Файл шифруется, а расшифровывается не очень правильно

Tags: c++, шифрование

Привет.

Я сделала программу для шифрования файлов. Шифруется нормально. А вот обратно - не все символы становятся такими, какими были - меняются на что-то иное. Помогите разобраться в чём дело. Уже у кого только не спрашивала.  Там в программе ещё статистика, но она меня не волнует на данный момент. Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void ZAPMASKEY(ifstream &, int *, int &);
void NEWDMASS(int *&, int &);
int main()
{
    int S1 = 50;
    //Для ключей
    ifstream FDK("fdk.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!FDK) {
        cout << "Can not open." << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    int *maskey = new int[S1];
    //отправляет заполнять массив ключей
    ZAPMASKEY(FDK, maskey, S1);
    //S1 - число ключей

    //Основная часть
    char w1, w2;
    char file1[100];
    char file2[100];
    //int b;
    //int kode;
    int i = -1;
    cout << "Your file input:";
    cin >> file1;
    cout << endl << "Your file output:";
    cin >> file2;
    ifstream KF1(file1, ios::binary);
    ofstream KF2(file2, ios::binary);
    //шифрует файл
    while (KF1) {
        KF1.get(w1);
        if (!KF1)
            break;
        i++;
        KF2.put((maskey[i % S1] ^ w1) % 256);
    }
    KF1.close();
    KF2.close();

    //Для статистики
    char c;
    cout << endl << "Do you want to see statistics?:";
    cin >> c;
    if (c == 'y') {
        char ck = 'y';
        while (ck == 'y') {
            int d;
            int MASSS[256];
            for (d = 0; d < 256; d++)
                MASSS[d] = 0;
            //char symbol;
            int code;
            cout << "symbol code: ";
            cin >> code;
            cout << "symbol: " << char (code) << endl;
            //symbol=char(code);
            //cout<<"symbol:";  cin>>symbol;
            ifstream KF3(file1, ios::binary);
            ifstream KF4(file2, ios::binary);
            //KF3.seekg(0); KF4.seekg(0);
            while (KF3) {
                KF3.get(w1);
                KF4.get(w2);
                if (w1 == char (code)) {
                    //kode=static_cast<int>(w2); 
                    MASSS[unsigned char (w2)] = MASSS[unsigned char (w2)] + 1;
                }
            }
            for (d = 0; d < 256; d++) {
                if (d % 16 == 0)
                    cout << endl;
                cout << setw(4) << MASSS[d];
            }
            KF3.close();
            KF4.close();
            cout << endl << "More?";
            cin >> ck;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void ZAPMASKEY(ifstream & FDKF, int *maskey, int &s1)
{
    int b;
    char w;
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < s1; j++)
        maskey[j] = 0;
    while (FDKF) {
        FDKF.get(w);
        if (w != ' ') //у меня в файле для ключей нет точек и переносов строки. я проверяла и у меня совпадало кол-во символов, размеры файлов, кол-во слов и т.д. 
        {
            if (!FDKF)
                break;
            b = static_cast < int >(w);
            maskey[i] = maskey[i] + b;
        } else {
            //cout<<k<<endl;
            maskey[i] = maskey[i] % 256;
            i++;
        }
        if ((i - s1) >= 0)
            NEWDMASS(maskey, s1);

    }
    s1 = i + 1; //пробовала возвращать и просто i, но мало чем помогло
}

void NEWDMASS(int *&MASKEY, int &s)
{
    int *maskey2 = new int[s * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < s * 2; i++)
        maskey2[i] = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)
        maskey2[j] = MASKEY[j];
    delete[]MASKEY;
    MASKEY = maskey2;
    s *= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[[@лэйла](/users/10446/%D0%BB%D1%8D%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0)](/users/10446/%D0%BB%D1%8D%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0), ошибочка нашлась!

Первая (очевидно опечатка) не компилируется в строке 74 unsigned char надо заключить в скобки.

Вторая - из-за нее и не работало - работа с **сылками**.
В объявлении и определении вместо

```
void ZAPMASKEY(ifstream&, int*, int&);
```

и соответственно

```
void ZAPMASKEY (ifstream &FDKF, int *maskey, int &s1)
{
   ...
```

надо написать

```
void ZAPMASKEY(ifstream&, int*&, int&);
```

и соответственно

```
void ZAPMASKEY (ifstream &FDKF, int *&maskey, int &s1)
{
   ...
```

поскольку Вы в ZAPMASKEY() вызываете NEWDMASS(), которая **меняет адрес в памяти** массива  maskey.

Далее могу только долго ругаться на авторов С++, которые сделали в языке механизм  ссылок *параллельно* с указателями.

По поводу собственно вопроса, могу сказать, что сформулирован он не корректно. На самом деле и шифрация и дешифрация не работали, т.к. для длинного файла ключей (больше 50 слов) массив, которым "ксорим", был просто случайным содержимым памяти.

По поводу того как надо (и не надо) писать, думаю, тут и без меня найдется достаточно желающих высказаться.